# Max Concurrent Connections in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api

I have Windows Service that accesses Outlook items through Exchange Web Service (EWS). It often experiences concurrency issues.

Based on [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), a maximum of 27 connections per user can be made concurrently for Exchange Online.  I couldn't find documentation for the detailed throttling policies for Microsoft Graph.

Is there anyone know if I can make more concurrent connections in Graph API than EWS? Also, does Graph API show better performance in general than EWS such as response time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling). There is also an in-depth look at [Throttling patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/throttling) available.

Each endpoint throttles a little differently. For Exchange/Outlook endpoints it is 10,000 requests per app id, per user,  within a 10 minute window.

The term "connections" doesn't really apply to an API like Microsoft Graph. As a REST-based API, it is fundamentally stateless. Each request is a self-contained transaction.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Can I understand that there is request limit per user within time window but no limit on concurrent transactions per user as far as he doesn't hit the request limit ?

Comment: There are no fixed numbers published but there if any tenant becomes overwhelmed it _will_ start throttling regardless of endpoint, app, or user. The guidance is to assume you could get a `429` at any point. As long as you handle the `429` you shouldn't run into too many issues.

Comment: I was asking the point when a tenant "becomes overwhelmed" in Graph API as EWS specifies it as 27 max concurrent transactions. From performance wise - do you know if Graph API is faster than EWS in terms of retrieving items etc?

Comment: EWS has slightly different throttling. "Overwhelmed" could mean something unrelated to what you're doing EWS or Graph. As for performance, it depends on what you're doing. In general, REST carries less overhead than SOAP but the difference is likely negligible for simple operations.